# How to clone git repo that have other repo in it?

Tags: github, git-clone

I'm trying to clone https://github.com/ornicar/lila to my PC. 
That project have a link to other project in https://github.com/ornicar/lila/tree/master/modules/chess
and when I simply do git clone git@github.com:ornicar/lila.git it doesn't clone chess content.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `git submodule update --init` after you clone the main repo.  It will fetch the other repo and place it in the proper location.